# How retrieve video tags from a youtube video in API v3 without use OAuth?

Tags: api, video, youtube, tags

I need get tags for filtering videos from a specific channel.
Its implemented in a audiovisual studio web as portfolio.
Obviously I want that this process be transparent for users.
Looks impossible achieve what I need without a OAuth authentication process...I already have tried it in some ways, failing whole times.
Thanks